# asp.net can't continue after response.binarywrite

Tags: asp.net, httpresponse

I have the following code which successfully writes a pdf to the client. The problem is that I can't get any code after this to execute. It's the last step of a wizard, and despite putting this in the ActiveStepChanged handler, it never makes it to the confirmation/final page.

```
                    Response.Clear()
                Response.ContentType = Nothing
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & FileName)
                Response.BinaryWrite(data)
                Response.Flush()
```

Basically, there's a checkbox that the user checks if they want to download the file when they hit the Finish button. I don't want to have a separate button to download the file because users have been known to get confused and think that by pressing the download button that they've completed the necessary steps and never complete their application (we're talking about non computer literate users here). So it all works, except it doesn't make it to the confirmation step when they select that option.

How can I ensure that processing continues after downloading the file?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to write this code in a HttpHandler and call Response.End after Response.Flush.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that hasn't made a difference. It still fails to execute any code after

Comment: @user1815872 a httpHandler is the same as an empty page.... and you do have to write Response.End after Response.Flush to end response.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out myself. Basically, I placed the response.binarywrite code (listed in op) in the code behind of its own empty webform. I then call then use the javascript openwindow function in ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock to open it.

Code in original page:

```
            Me.Session("PrintApplication") = data
            Me.Session("PrintApplicationFileName") = FileName

            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType, "PrintReport", "window.open('PrintApplication.aspx');", True)
```

Code in PrintApplication.aspx:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Me.Session("PrintApplicationFileName") <> Nothing Then
        Dim data As Byte() = Me.Session("PrintApplication")
        Dim FileName As String = Me.Session("PrintApplicationFileName")

        Me.Session("PrintApplication") = Nothing
        Me.Session("PrintApplicationFileName") = Nothing
        Response.Clear()
        Response.ContentType = Nothing
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & FileName)
        Response.BinaryWrite(data)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.End()

    End If

End Sub
```

Works perfectly