# Download PDF using Response on ASPX Page only working in Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, http, pdf, download

I've seen several questions relating to downloading a PDF from a Web browser using Response, but none seem to fit the mysterious issue I'm having.

I am working on a project that requires the user to be able to click a button (btnPDF) to instantly download a PDF of a Telerik report with a specific "ID" string to the Downloads folder. This process was originally located in an ASPX Page on an IIS separate from where the button is located. When btnPDF was clicked, I used Response.Redirect to download the PDF through that page. The code to download the PDF looked like this:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = result.MimeType 'this is always "application/pdf"
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private)
Response.Expires = -1
Response.Buffer = True
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0};FileName={1}", "attachment", fileName))
Response.BinaryWrite(result.DocumentBytes)
Response.End()
```

Note that result.DocumentBytes is a byte array containing correct bytes for the PDF.

**This code worked fine.** Now, instead of having the process on a separate Page in a separate project, I need to merge the process onto the same page where btnPDFis located, so that when you click btnPDF, a subroutine is called that performs the same task. I thought this would be very easy, pretty much a copy and paste. With the same code added in a new subroutine, this is what my click event handler "ButtonPDF_Click" now looks like:

```
Protected Sub ButtonPDF_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPDF.Click

    DownloadReportPDF(Me.RadGrid1.SelectedValue.ToString())

    Dim strMessage As String = "alert('Printed PDF Sheet.');"
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "MyScript", strMessage, True)

End Sub

Protected Sub DownloadReportPDF(ByVal releaseMasterId As String)
    'Service call to generate report source
    Dim service As New TelerikReportLibrary.ReportServices.PPSReportService
    Dim source As Telerik.Reporting.TypeReportSource = service.GetReportSource(releaseMasterId)

    'Render PDF and download
    Dim reportProcessor As New ReportProcessor()
    Dim result As RenderingResult = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", source, Nothing)

    Dim fileName As String = result.DocumentName + "_" + releaseMasterId + "." + result.Extension

    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = result.MimeType 'this is always "application/pdf"
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private)
    Response.Expires = -1
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0};FileName={1}", "attachment", fileName))
    Response.BinaryWrite(result.DocumentBytes)
    Response.End()

End Sub
```

**But the PDF no longer downloads.** An accurate byte array is still created, but the Response portion does not result in the PDF being downloaded from the browser. I've found that putting a call to DownloadReportPDF in the Page_Load handler on the same Page successfully generates and downloads a PDF as it did before.

I can't see any reason why this isn't working, but I'm new to ASP, and I'm not great in VB. I've tried using Response.OutputStream, Response.WriteFile, and making use of a MemoryStream, among several other things that I've lost track of. I'm hoping there's something simple, maybe some sort of property of the Page or btnPDF I could be missing. Here is the markup for btnPDF, just in case:

```
    <asp:linkButton ID="btnPDF" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Width="115px">
        <i class="fa fa-file-text" title="Edit"></i> PDF
    </asp:linkButton>
```

What could be causing such a problem? Where should I look at this point?

Let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks,
Shane

EDIT:

I experimented with setting a session variable on btnPDF_Click, and handling the PDF download on postback. Again, a valid byte array was generated, but the HttpResponse did not cause the PDF to download from the browser.

EDIT:

Building on the last edit, this tells me that calling DownloadReportPDF from Page_Load works only when IsPostBack is false. I just tested this thought, and it holds true. In the above code, if I check IsPostBack at the moment I'm trying to download the PDF, it is true. Investigating further.

Comment: I think that the problem must have something to do with the button click launching a postback. You'll probably need to play with `IsPostBack`...

Comment: Are you doing async post inside update panel?

Comment: @Pikoh: I reconfigured the process using IsPostBack and session variables, but the problem persists. Please see edited post. Thanks! (Also, I am not doing async post as far as I know)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I finally found a solution I'm satisfied with (though I still don't understand *why* I can't download the PDF using Response while IsPostBack is true).

Inspired by [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796224/asp-net-cant-continue-after-response-binarywrite), I put the previously posted code in an HttpHandler called PDFDownloadHandler, then used Response.Redirect in the btnPDF_Click event handler to utilize PDFDownloadHandler. [This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx) helped me a lot on that process, as it is something I have not done before.

In case anyone else runs into this problem, here is the new PDFDownloadHandler:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Web
Imports Telerik.Reporting
Imports Telerik.Reporting.Processing

Public Class PDFDownloadHandler
    Implements IHttpHandler

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As  _
            System.Web.HttpContext) Implements _
            System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        Dim request As HttpRequest = context.Request
        Dim response As HttpResponse = context.Response

        Dim path As String = request.Path
        If path.Contains("pps.pdfdownload") Then
            Dim releaseMasterId As String = request.QueryString("ID")
            If releaseMasterId IsNot Nothing Then
                'Service call to generate report source
                Dim service As New TelerikReportLibrary.ReportServices.PPSReportService
                Dim source As Telerik.Reporting.TypeReportSource = service.GetReportSource(releaseMasterId)

                'Render PDF and save
                Dim reportProcessor As New ReportProcessor()
                Dim result As RenderingResult = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", source, Nothing)

                Dim fileName As String = result.DocumentName + "_" + releaseMasterId + "." + result.Extension

                response.Clear()
                response.ContentType = result.MimeType
                response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private)
                response.Expires = -1
                response.Buffer = True
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0};FileName={1}", "attachment", fileName))
                response.BinaryWrite(result.DocumentBytes)
            End If
        End If

        response.End()
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean _
            Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Any further insight on why the original technique did not work is greatly appreciated.